# Dash line with custom model not static

Tags: qgis, symbology, rendering

I have a line layer which I want to represent as dash line with fixed position. I made a custom dash model with map units for space and dash :

[image]

But when I display it, the dashes move with the view :

[image]

Is there a way to fix the render of the dash line layer from the start point of the line ?

Comment: It's a simple straight line starting at a reference point (on an airfield runway) and ending to the opposite of the runway. The spacing between dashes is 1.3m and the dashes are 1.5m long. In fact, when the starting point is included in the view, it stays fixed but when I move the view out this starting point, the lines update and start to move.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be working:

Use a Geometry Generator expression for the symbol:

```
 apply_dash_pattern( geometry:=$geometry,
 pattern:=array(10, 5))
```

This will create a multiline with segments 10 m long, and a gap of 5 meters (if your crs have units in meters).

[image]

The grey dashes stay in the same location relative to the white crossing when panning:
[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. `apply_dash_pattern` appears to be a QGIS 3.24 new feature. What is the difference with the dash line style I used ?

Comment: Nice! Apply dash pattern is creating a multiline geometry from the input line